# Figure placement

Tags: math-mode, floats

How does one make a figure appear precisely where it is placed in the coding, as opposed to the top of the next page? This is an issue for me currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float.sty`. Then use `H` as the position specifier.

Normally, we use `[!tbp]` as float position specifier to place our floats. Here the interpretations are,

> t (Top) - at the top of a text page.
>
> b (Bottom) - at the bottom of a
>   text page.
>
> p (Page of floats) - on a separate float page, which is a
>   page containing no text, only floats.

Should you want to place where you want it, you will use the `h` (for ‘here’) specifier. Even if you use the placement specifier `h`, the figure or table will not be printed *here* if doing so would break the rules. Under that circumstances, you want to send a stronger message and you will want to go for the above mentioned `H` solution.

When put the  `!` LaTeX overrides certain internal parameters it uses for determining good float positions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  HERE
  \caption{Place it here}
  \label{fig:h}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

`\lipsum` is only for dummy text, in case it confuses you in any manner.

Comment: Using a float environment and then keeping this environment off from floating is contradicting. The »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« package with its `\captionof` command is probably the better way to go.